# Get depicted people from a wikipedia file

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

How can I get the list of depicted people from a wikipedia file?

Example: I have a file with article ID 5457009. The wikipedia link is http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_B_145_Bild-F048807-0025,_Bonn,_Neubau_Kanzleramt,_Schmidt_im_Arbeitszimmer.jpg

What would the API request look like to extract the people meta data from this file (Schmidt, Helmut: Bundeskanzler, Verteidigungsminister, SPD, Bundesrepublik Deutschland)

Here is another example with 3 depicted people: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bundesarchiv_B_145_Bild-F009740-0002,_Presseclub_Bonn,_Bildungspolitiker_aus_Finnland.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, this information is not stored in any structured manner — the table you see on the image description page is just a MediaWiki template that renders to an HTML table.

To extract the information from the template, you basically have three options:

1. [Fetch the raw wiki markup](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&titles=File%3aBundesarchiv_B_145_Bild-F048807-0025,_Bonn,_Neubau_Kanzleramt,_Schmidt_im_Arbeitszimmer.jpg) of the image description page using `prop=revisions` and `rvprop=content` and parse it yourself.  Unfortunately, parsing wikitext reliably can be a bit tricky, but several [MediaWiki bot frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCreating_a_bot) come with pretty good parsers built in.
2. [Fetch the parsed HTML version of the page](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=parse&prop=text&page=File%3aBundesarchiv_B_145_Bild-F048807-0025,_Bonn,_Neubau_Kanzleramt,_Schmidt_im_Arbeitszimmer.jpg) using `action=parse` and use a standard HTML parser to extract the text from the table.
3. Since [MediaWiki 1.20](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Release_notes/1.20), you also have the option to tell MediaWiki to parse the template markup for you and [return an XML parse tree](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38231) by passing the parameter `generatexml=1` to either [`prop=revisions`](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&rvgeneratexml=1&titles=File%3aBundesarchiv_B_145_Bild-F048807-0025,_Bonn,_Neubau_Kanzleramt,_Schmidt_im_Arbeitszimmer.jpg) or [`action=parse`](http://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?format=jsonfm&action=parse&prop=&generatexml=1&page=File%3aBundesarchiv_B_145_Bild-F048807-0025,_Bonn,_Neubau_Kanzleramt,_Schmidt_im_Arbeitszimmer.jpg).  The relevant part will look something like this (reformatted for readability):

```xml
<template>
  <title>BArch-image</title>
  ...
  <part>
    <name>depicted people</name> =
    <value>
      * Schmidt, Helmut: Bundeskanzler, Verteidigungsminister, SPD, Bundesrepublik Deutschland
    </value>
  </part>
  ...
</template>
```

This is not a perfectly clean representation of the data — it still contains some unparsed wikitext elements, like the `*` denoting a bulleted list item — but it should be much easier to parse than the completely raw MediaWiki template markup.

Comment: this looks very promising. I like your third approach and I will give it a try.